# How to capture Image without a button click using Camera2 API in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera2

Does anybody have experience in using Camera2 API? I want to capture Image without user interaction (Button click) and by using background Service. I have used Google's sample project of Camera2 API. Please help me. Right now, I can only able to capture images using Activity and on a button click.
Below is my code:

```
public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
int mPictureCounter = 0;
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private static final String TAG = "Camera2BasicFragment";
private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0, STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1, STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2, STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3, STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920, MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
    }
};
private String mCameraId;
private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private Size mPreviewSize;
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
};
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private File mFile;
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + "" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".jpg");
        Log.e("TestingProject", "\n\n\n--------------------------------**********************************\n" +
                "Files Absolute Path : " + mFile.getAbsolutePath()
                + "\n**********************************--------------------------------\n\n\n");
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
    }
};
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
private boolean mFlashSupported;
private int mSensorOrientation;
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if (afState == null) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                        CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else {runPrecaptureSequence();}}
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null ||
                        aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                        aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                    mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                    captureStillPicture();}
                break;}}}
    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                    @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                    @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {process(partialResult);}
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {process(result);}
};
private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });}}
private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
                                      int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
            if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                    option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            } else {notBigEnough.add(option);}}
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());} else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[0];}
}
public static Camera2BasicFragment newInstance() {return new Camera2BasicFragment();}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "proof_" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".jpg");
    Log.e("TestingProject", "\n\n\n--------------------------------**********************************\n" +
            "File Path : " + mFile.getAbsolutePath()
            + "\n**********************************--------------------------------\n\n\n");
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();
    if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());} else {
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);}
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
}
private void requestCameraPermission() {
    if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.request_permission))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    } else {super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);}}
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {continue;}
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                continue;
            }

            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                    mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

            int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
            }

            Point displaySize = new Point();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
            int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
            int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

            if (swappedDimensions) {
                rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
            }

            if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
            }

            if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
            }
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                    maxPreviewHeight, largest);
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }
            Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

            mCameraId = cameraId;

            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    }
}

private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}
private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}
private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);            mPreviewRequestBuilder=mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        if (null == mCameraDevice){return;}
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();                                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);} catch (CameraAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {showToast("Failed");}
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
private void takePicture() {
    lockFocus();
}
private void lockFocus() {
    try {
        List<CaptureRequest> captureList = new ArrayList<CaptureRequest>();
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            captureList.add(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build());
        }
        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.captureBurst(captureList, cameraCaptureCallback, null);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.removeTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback cameraCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,TotalCaptureResult result) {
        Log.e("TestingProject", "pic # " + (mPictureCounter + 1));
        mPictureCounter++;
        if (mPictureCounter >= 10)
            unlockFocus();
    }
};
private void runPrecaptureSequence() {
    try {            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
   mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void captureStillPicture() {
    try {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {return;}
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };
        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
    return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
}
private void unlockFocus() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
        mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e("TestingProject", "BHAND... "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.picture: {
            takePicture();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.info: {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                        .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (mFlashSupported) {
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
    }
}

private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    private final Image mImage;
    private final File mFile;

    public ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }

}
public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
        ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

}
public static class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(R.string.request_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Activity activity = parent.getActivity();
                                if (activity != null) {
                                    activity.finish();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please explain the problems you encountered to move the code to a service.

Comment: I need to capture image without user interaction... The method takePicture() is used to capture image. When I call this method in onViewCreated or onActivityCreated, App crashes. My first goal is to atleast capture images as sson as the activity opens

Comment: Then you did inform us wrong. So this code is not even working. Ok. Then post the logcat with the errors/exceptions.

Comment: Are you stating that when you call `takePicture()`in `onClick()` the code works?

Comment: Where did you define and instantiate `bigEnough`?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience... Actually due to restrictions of characters I removed comments from code and by mistake i have deleted 2 lines

Comment: List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>(); put this line above this line List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Remove this mCaptureCallback, from the definition method lockFocus()

Comment: I have edited the above code and made corrections.

Comment: `Are you stating that when you call takePicture()in onClick() the code works?`

Comment: yes. The code is working when I call takePicture() in onClick

Comment: `When I call this method in onViewCreated or onActivityCreated, App crashes`. Yes. But not without printing a stacktrace and an exception in the LogCat. That info tells it all. Please post the relevant part from the logcat and comment.